# Not all $_Post values are being sent to table.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, post

I made a form using jotform.com and did not tweak anything just changed the action="" to my .php file for $_POST query. I have the same file print the $_POST array to verify all values are received from the html so I will not include the html code. I have included the .php below and after a form submittal .php prints the following array confirming that all has been posted:

```
successArray ( [formID] => 32750985631157 [q1_referral] => John Doe [q12_contactType] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Prospect ) ) [q3_companyNameindividual] => John Doe\'s Company [q4_dba] => John Doe\'s D.B.A [q15_mainofficePhone] => Array ( [area] => 305 [phone] => 8654565 ) [q28_mainContact] => Array ( [first] => John [last] => Doe ) [q8_address] => Array ( [addr_line1] => 1223 Cedar Ave [addr_line2] => N/A [city] => Miami [state] => Florida [postal] => 33054 [country] => United States ) [q32_email32] => johndoe@email.com [q11_website11] => johndoe@johndoe.com [q29_secondaryContact] => Array ( [first] => [last] => ) [q10_mainofficePhone10] => Array ( [area] => [phone] => ) [q13_mobilePhone13] => Array ( [area] => [phone] => ) [q14_fax14] => Array ( [area] => [phone] => ) [q20_homePhone20] => Array ( [area] => [phone] => ) [q26_otherPhone] => Array ( [area] => [phone] => ) [q30_email2] => [q31_email3] => [q27_secondaryAddress] => Array ( [addr_line1] => [addr_line2] => [city] => [state] => [postal] => [country] => ) [q23_notes] => [website] => [simple_spc] => 32750985631157-32750985631157 )
```

All columns in mysql table are set to varchar with 255 limit other than id of course. The values that don't show up on mysql table are:

```
main_contact     varchar(255)           
main_phone   varchar(255)           
main_address     varchar(255)           
Main_address2    varchar(255)           
main_city    varchar(255)           
main_state   varchar(255)           
main_postcode    varchar(255)           
main_country     varchar(255)
```

I have been beating my head for hours making sure I wrote the php correctly. If no one has a solution I will post the other codes. Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
require_once('info.php');

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO contacts(referral,name,dba,main_contact,main_phone,main_address,main_address2,main_city,main_state,main_postcode,main_country,main_email,website_address)VALUES('".$_POST['q1_referral']."','".$_POST['q3_companyNameindividual']."','".$_POST['q4_dba']."','".$_POST['q28_mainContact[first]']."','".$_POST['q15_mainofficePhone[phone]']."','".$_POST['q8_address[addr_line1]']."','".$_POST['q8_address[addr_line2]']."','".$_POST['q8_address[city]']."','".$_POST['q8_address[state]']."','".$_POST['q8_address[postal]']."','".$_POST['q8_address[country]']."','".$_POST['q32_email32']."','".$_POST['q11_website11']."')");

echo "success";
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: If you're going to use mysqli, take advantage of it and parametrize. You're code is wide open for mysql injection

Comment: I am a novice and wanted to focus on functionality before security. Are you advising that I should learn both at the same time or are these security issues that can be patched later? Also I will google what you mean by parameterization but if you have a moment could you provide a brief ex.? Thank you for your input.

Comment: Always do both, that way you don't forget to change things in the future when it goes live. I'm more versed in PDO than mysqli, but check out this for starters: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using subscripts incorrectly.

For example, you're referring to:

```
$_POST['q28_mainContact[first]']
```

But in fact you should be looking at

```
$_POST['q28_mainContact']['first']
```

Your other fields are similarly incorrect.

Comment: The solution you provided fixed the issue. I am very appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have used the concatenation operator where you are inserting values i.e here

```
('".$_POST['q1_referral']."','".$_POST['q3_companyNameindividual']."','".$_POST['q4_dba']."','".$_POST['q28_mainContact[first]']."','".$_POST['q15_mainofficePhone[phone]']."','".$_POST['q8_address[addr_line1]']."','".$_POST['q8_address[addr_line2]']."','".$_POST['q8_address[city]']."','".$_POST['q8_address[state]']."','".$_POST['q8_address[postal]']."','".$_POST['q8_address[country]']."','".$_POST['q32_email32']."','".$_POST['q11_website11']."')"
```

and then remove the double quotes so it should look more like this

```
('$_POST[q1_referral]','$_POST[q3_companyNameindividual]',
```

PS: I have done it only for first two members to give you an idea.